# Twitter-Bootstrap Scrollspy

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm tying to implement Twitter-Bootstrap Scrollspy on a menu so that when the user scrolls to a section of the page the css class is changed. This proven to be beyond frustrating.  I'm already using the affix code from the code which works great.

So from my code below when a user scrolls to the LI element of `#ScrollSpyContent` I want to change the class of `.product_submenu_image` to `.product_submenu_active`.

How can I do this?

(I'm using jsp's in `java` so their might be some java code in here. I tried to strip out most of it.)

Thanks.

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">   
 <head>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap.css"/>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap-responsive.css"/>
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes">
</head>

    <body> 
        <header></header>
        <div class="row-fluid product_submenu">
            <nav class="span10 offset1">
                <ul class="productmenus">
                    <li><a href="#product_features"><div class="product_submenu_image"><img src="../img/product_computer.png" alt=""/>&nbsp;Product Features</div></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#gettingstarted"><div class="product_submenu_image product_submenu_border"><img src="../img/product_people.png" alt=""/>&nbsp;Getting Started</div></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#product_support"><div class="product_submenu_image product_submenu_border"><img src="../img/product_phone.png" alt=""/>&nbsp;Product Support</div></a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>  
        </div>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <nav class="row-fluid" >      
                <ul class="span10 offset1" data-spy="scroll">       
                    <li class="row-fluid" id="product_features"></li> <!-- End Product Features -->
                    <li class="row-fluid" id="gettingstarted"></li> <!-- End Getting Started  -->
                    <li class="row-fluid" id="product_support"></li><!-- End Product support  -->
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>        
        <footer></footer>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
        <script src="/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
        <script>
        $(function() {
          var $spy = $('.productmenus');
          $spy.scrollspy({offset: 20});
          $spy.bind("activate", function(e) {
            //e.target is the current <li> element
            var header = $(e.target).find(".product_submenu_image");
            $(header).addClass('active');
          });
        });    
        </script>
     </body>
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
.product_submenu_image
{
    background: url('../img/product_tab_default.gif');
    max-height: 100%;
    padding: 18% 0 18% 0;
    border: none;
}

.product_submenu_image.active
{
    background: blue;
    /*background: url('../img/product_tab_selected.gif');*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So you need to use the scroll spy `activate` event described here: 
http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#scrollspy

Basically you need some code like so:

```
$(function() {
  var $spy = $('.nav.nav-pills');
  $spy.scrollspy({offset: 20});
  $spy.bind("activate", function(e) {
    // do stuff here when a new section is in view
  });
});
```

Here is a working example: 
http://jsfiddle.net/hajpoj/f2z6u/3/

please ignore the fact that it starts at the bottom... not sure if that a unrelated or related bug, but the main point is  you can see how the activate event works

Comment: I've updated my code above with some of your suggestions. I must be missing something because it still is not working. Not working...meaning I can't see any indication that something is being triggered when scrolling

Comment: So i notice a couple things: (1) you need to have `.nav` class on `ul` element as scrollspy depends on that. (2) for what you are doing you don't need my code. When scrollspy is working properly, it adds a class `.active` on your `li` element. so you could change your second css from `.product_submenu_image.active` to `.active .product_submenu_image` . To help in your debugging try using chrome developer tools or firebug to make sure the `active` class is being added to your li elements. I originally thought you wanted to change the your *content* not your *nav*